# get(id) brings back id and null, why?

Tags: javascript, get, mootools, alert

im using mootools to get the id from an element and it doesnt work, it brigns back the id and null.

```
  $$(".obj").addEvent("click",function(){
   var objid=this.get("id");
  alert(objid);
  });
```

this works normally in jsfiddle but if you try the code inside you pc it doesnt. it will bring you back 2 alerts one after the other, one with the id and one with null.

why is this happening?

this is the whole thing

http://jsfiddle.net/hgXWm/

Comment: The alert not run? or returns null? For me your code works fine.

Comment: @Gustavo Costa De Oliveira it does work but it brings back 2 alerts, the first one is the id and after you click ok on the alert another one pops up and sais only null, and i treid this on 2 different computers and i got the same thing and in different browsers

Comment: Its occurs when the event bound two times. Check your code to be sure if this code doesn't duplicate or into a loop. If is possible show me the more code

Comment: @Gustavo Costa De Oliveira i posted the code, and now i understand why it happens, but still how can i make it bring only the id of the element being clicked since i only need that not the other one.

Answer (score 2):

On a brief read on mootools documentation I think that your problem can be solved this way:

```
$$(".obj").addEvent("click",function(e){
   var objid = $(this).get("id");
   e.stop();
});
```

This force event propagation to stop and not run to ancestors.

Comment: `$(this)` isn't needed.  `this` is already extended (differs from jQuery).  Also, e.stop() stops everything, stopPropagation is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If it works in jsfiddle, then it works.  The problem is in the rest of your code.

`$$` returns a collection of elements.  If you call an `Element` method on a collection of elements, it magically calls it on every element (much like jQuery).  My guess is, as others have pointed out, that you've got a bubbling issue.  When you click one `.obj` you are also clicking a parent element that shares the class.

#### Reproduced problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/rpflorence/hgXWm/4/

#### The fix

http://jsfiddle.net/rpflorence/hgXWm/5/

You just need to use `event.stopPropagation()`

Also, in your original code there, you don't need the ID.  All that $(objId) is useless, you already have `this`.  Just use it, it's the same thing as $(objId) except faster because you've already got it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the markup. Maybe the clicked element has an ancestor which also has the class "obj" but no ID. The click would bubble up to the ancestor.

See the fiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/cf3Aw/

Comment: i put jsfiddle link, but like i said there it works fine but if you use this normally it will give out that extra thing, and yes its like you said, but i dont understand why it would give me that null since im not asking for all the ids, only the id of "this"